# ¿Cómo instalar php-mbregex en ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Necesito instalar el módulo mbregex. Actualmente tengo php7. ¿Saben qué paquete debo instalar?

Comment: Más allá de que probablemente lo necesites por compatibilidad con algún script viejo, vale mencionar que mbregex usa como motor de expresiones regulares a Oniguruma, el cual es mucho menos potente que PCRE, usando las funciones `preg_*()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas `mbstring` puedes instalarlo con:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

puedes cambiar el `7.0` por la version exacta de tu PHP.

**NO olvides reiniciar el servicio:**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me funcionó perfectamente.